# Vertically center a div - Browser Compatibility

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

Let's say I have a container Div `A` of unknown height and inside it a Div `B` of known height

```
A                                                    
┌─────────────────────────────────┐  ▲               
│                                 │  │               
│    B                            │  │               
│   ┌─────────────────────────┐   │  │               
│   │▲                        │   │                  
│   ││Known Height            │   │  Unknown Height  
│   │▼                        │   │                  
│   └─────────────────────────┘   │  │               
│                                 │  │               
│                                 │  │               
└─────────────────────────────────┘  ▼
```

I want to vertically center B within A. Now I have found these two methods, both using absolute positioning.

## Technique 1

```
.B {
    /* height has to be declared or it won't work */
    height: 200px; 
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

In this case the height must be declared to make this work. 
Also it doesn't work on windows phone.
Reference: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

## Technique 2

```
.B {
    /* we have to set width and height */
    height: 120px;
    width: 960px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -60px;      /* half of the .B div height */
    margin-left: -480px;    /* half of the .B div widht */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

}
```

Also in this case we have to know the height of the contained `B` div.
Reference: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Which one of these two is the most cross-browser compatible technique ?
Does exist a more broad solution for this problem working on most of the browser (from IE8 as lower requirements).

Comment: I edited the question to avoid opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two other methods:

### **1. Using pseudo-element on the container**

```
#container:before {
   content:'';
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
   height:100%;
}

#content {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This method should be compatible with most browsers except IE8 and below: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ms1y9ey9/)

Note that in this case, the element being vertically centered needs to have `display:inline-block`

### **2. Using `display:table-cell;`**

```
#container {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This method should be compatible with 99.98% of the browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20table

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8m2rh8p7/)

Comment: How about compatibility as my original question?

Comment: @Leonardo Well, method 1 is ok with 98.98% of browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20table). Method 1 should also work on every browser except IE8 and lower (http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore)

Comment: You have a typo I guess

Comment: @Leonardo on which one?

Comment: In your comment you only mentioned method 1 twice, I tough maybe you wanted to comment about 1 and 2, am I wrong?

Comment: @Leonardo my bad. That was indeed a typo. I can't edit the comment now, but I menat method *2* in the first example. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.B {
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Example1:** http://jsfiddle.net/k477zumz/ (Only vertical Centering)

**Example2:** http://jsfiddle.net/k477zumz/1/ (Both vertical and horizontal centering)

Comment: Clean and short solution, though it won't work in IE8 and below, and Opera Mini (http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Answer (score 0):

If size of the element B is known than absolute positioning with negative margins is more solid solution. It works well in most browsers.

Comment: Thanks, any reference to support the statement about browser compatibility?

Comment: IE4, FF1, Chome1, Opera4  
for positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility
  
for margins:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Browser_compatibility